# Swift/SpriteKit: Attempting to reach a function/method in a class from another class not working

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I have a function in my ScoreSystem class named addScore. The function adds 1 point to the game, updates the SKLabelNode to the current score and in turn calls the function startNewLevel every 25 points.

```
func addScore(scene: SKScene) {
    gameScore += 1
    scoreLabel.text = "\(gameScore)"

    if CGFloat(gameScore).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 25) == 0 {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name.init("start_new_level"), object: nil)
        GameScreen().displayLevel(scene: scene)
    }
}
```

The function gets called every time a torpedo that has been fired hits the enemy. I now want to add a new level where meteors (SKSpriteNode) have to be avoided. I have several SKActions in a sequence to accomplish this. Essentially, the SKSpriteNode moves from the top of the screen, reaches below the screen and gets deleted. If the meteor reaches the bottom of the screen means that it has been avoided by the player.

I'm attempting to call the function addScore but it doesn't update.

Here is the function:

```
let scoreSystem = ScoreSystem()

func spawnMeteor() {

    let randomXStart = CGFloat.random(min: gameArea.minX, max: gameArea.maxX)

    let startPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXStart, y: scene.size.height * 1.2)
    let endPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXStart, y: -scene.size.height * 0.2)


    let meteor = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "meteor")
    meteor.name = "Meteor"
    meteor.zPosition = 2
    meteor.position = startPoint

    let moveMeteor = SKAction.move(to: endPoint, duration: 3)
    let deleteEnemy = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    let score = SKAction.run(addToScore)

    let meteorSequence = SKAction.sequence([
        moveMeteor,
        score,
        deleteEnemy])

    scene.addChild(meteor)
    meteor.run(meteorSequence)

}
```

I have tried a function addToScore like this:

```
func addToScore() {
    scoreSystem.addScore(scene: scene!)
}
```

And also tried this

```
func addToScore() {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name.init("add_to_score"), object: nil)
}
```

When trying this second alternative, I add the following to the GameScene

```
override func sceneDidLoad() {
    super.sceneDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name.init("add_to_score"), object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self] (notification) in
        self?.scoreSystem.addScore(scene: self!)
    }

}
```

I removed several lines from the spawnMeteor() function so not to clog the space with unnecessary lines of code. I have yet to figure out how to call that function using SKAction.run(). Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `addToScore`, is it called?

Comment: Good call. No, it isn't. Why?

Comment: Instead of calling a middle function to reach the addScore(), I'm calling the function from the SKAction.run() as follows: let score = SKAction.run(scoreSystem.addScore) but I get the following error: Cannot convert value of type '(SKScene) -> ()' to expected argument type '() -> Void'. I've searched for answers of how to fix that but don't quite understand what it means to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing along a lot of information to your functions, probably too much.

I would suggest either you implement Protocols or Notifications to handle your information, personally I prefer protocols so my example will be protocols.

I am making some assumptions about your code because not all of it is presented in your question...

```
protocol ScoreSystemDelegate: class {
    func displayLevel()
}

class ScoreSystem: SKNode {

    weak var scoreSystemDelegate: ScoreSystemDelegate! 

    //your init func and any other funcs in this class (unknown)

    func addScore(scene: SKScene) {
        gameScore += 1
        scoreLabel.text = "\(gameScore)"

        if CGFloat(gameScore).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 25) == 0 {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name.init("start_new_level"), object: nil)
            //GameScreen().displayLevel(scene: scene)
            self.scoreSystemDelegate.displayLevel()
        }
   }
}
```

in your class that creates the scoreSystem (assuming GameScene)...

```
class GameScene: SKScene, ScoreSystemDelegate {

    let scoreSystem = ScoreSystem()
    //assign GameScene as the delegate of ScoreSystem that way the 2 can communicate
    scoreSystem.scoreSystemDelegate = self

    func displayLevel() {
        //do whatever you do when you display the level
    }
}
```

now your spawn meteor func should work as you have coded because addScore no longer takes a scene property, nice thing about this approach is that you can make any object a delegate of ScoreSystem it doesn't have to be a scene.